# How to parse JSON without attribute name

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
options: [
"6GB RAM/128GB",
"8GB RAM/128GB",
"12GB RAM/256GB"
]
```

This JSON I want to parse using struct.

I have coded upto this :

```
struct Atts: Codable {
    let options: [Options]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case options
    }
}

struct Options: Codable {

}
```

But How to access the three elements in the "options" array?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: It's just an array of String, which conforms to Codable as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let options: [Options]
```

With

```
let options: [String]
```

And remove `struct Options: Codable {`  Also using `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {` is meaningless here as you don't change key name so remove it also , so all you need is

```
struct Atts: Codable {
   let options: [String]
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having an issue in this case

Comment: How can this "options" be assigned to an array?.. Like I have done "var jsondata = [json]()"  this previously!